# How to check if is moment()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

Ok, so I saw that to check if an `Object` is `moment` I need to check with the method `moment.isMoment(obj)` but when I try to validate `moment().toDate()` it tells me that it's false.

How may I check if an Object is `moment` whether it's `.toDate()` or not?

```
moment.isMoment(moment()) // true
moment.isMoment(moment().toDate()) // false
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A JS `Date` is a native date object, not a `Moment` object.  So `moment.isMoment(...)` returns false, because it isn't an instance of `Moment`.

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/

> How may I check if an Object is moment whether it's .toDate() or not?

The way you did in the question.  It's correctly returning false.